# Finding elements that don't have an attribute

Tags: vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm having trouble finding the syntax that will return the list of `UL` that do not have an `ID` attribute.

The following will return Nothing

```
For Each ul As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@id='']")
```

I know it's possible to return all `UL` and then to a separate using an If statement, but is there a way for HtmlAgilityPack to return the list of `UL` that don't have an `ID` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//ul[not(@id)]` will do the trick.

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ xmllint index.html --xpath '//ul[not(@id)]/text()'
1
3
```

where `index.html` contains:

```
<div>
    <ul>1</ul>
    <ul id="test">2</ul>
    <ul>3</ul>
</div>
```